# Azure limit of syncing tables from on-prem SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, azure, synchronization

I'm using Azure sync agent to sync the tables from an on-premise SQL Server database to Azure Portal SQL database.

This screenshot shows the results displayed for the database with the tables:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KS3QL.png)

When I select a database with multiple tables i.e (500+ tables), I'll get messages as 'no results' as seen in the screenshot here:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyN62.png)

Why is this? Is there any limitation for syncing the tables?

Please help me out..